# Skill needed to do advance level sas programming

Tags: programming-languages, sas

what is the best procedure to increase advance level SAS programming skill when there is no such requirement to use those concepts. Most of the time I complete my task using basic SAS concepts like set function, merge function or some other basic function. What is your suggestion if one wants to increase the programming capabilities.

Comment: You could try practicing / improving your skills on https://sasensei.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to venture a single 'best' option, but here are a few ideas:

- I haven't gone down this route myself, but you could look into studying for the SAS certifications to broaden your SAS knowledge.
- If you don't already know any SQL, that's something that's probably worth learning, as it's more transferable than most other SAS-related knowledge.
- If you find yourself writing lots of very similar bits of code, learn how to use arrays and write macros (and when not to write macros).
- If your code is taking a long time to run, read up on optimisation techniques and see if you can find faster ways of doing the same things. E.g. hash objects, indexes and parallel processing.